# Obtener valor para posterior petición ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

En este código estoy mostrando con javascript los registros de mysql a través de una petición ajax. Ahora quiero, pulsando el botón, ejecutar la función eliminar pero necesito sacar el valor de datos[i].dorsal para enviarlo como parámetro con ajax y no sé cómo. Gracias por la ayuda.

````
    var elemento= document.createElement('tr');
    elemento.innerHTML += "<td>"+"<button id='eliminar' class='boton' onclick=eliminar()>"+'Eliminar'+"</button>"+"</td>";
    elemento.innerHTML += '<td id="dorsal">'+datos[i].dorsal+'</td>';
    elemento.innerHTML += '<td id="datos">'+datos[i].nombre+'</td>';
    elemento.innerHTML += '<td>'+datos[i].posicion+'</td>';
    tabla.appendChild(elemento);
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

Lo único que necesitas es pasar ese valor como argumento a la función `eliminar`.

En el momento en que defines ese botón (o el HTML, vaya), conoces `i` y conoces `datos`, por lo que puedes aprovecharlos.

```javascript
// ...
const { dorsal, nombre, posicion } = datos[i];
const elemento = document.createElement('tr');
elemento.innerHTML = 
`
  <td>
    <button class="boton eliminar" onclick="eliminar(${dorsal})">Eliminar</button>
  </td>
  <td class="dorsal">${dorsal}</td>
  <td class="datos">${nombre}</td>
  <td>${posicion}</td>
`;
tabla.appendChild(elemento);
```

Ahora puedes cambiar la función `eliminar` para que reciba ese dato por parámetro.

```
function eliminar(dorsal) {
  // ...
}
```

> *Disclaimer*
> Por si te confunde un poco la sintaxis, te dejo la [documentación de los *template literals*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) y de [*destructuring assignments*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).
> Por otra parte, he quitado los `id` de los elementos dentro de la *row* porque conceptualmente deben ser un atributo único y, por el contexto, me imagino que esa tabla tendrá más de una *row* (el *array* `datos` puede tener más de un elemento, potencialmente), por lo que esos `id` se repetirían. Si realmente necesitas los `id`, te recomendaría hacer algo como `id="dorsal-${i}"`, por ejemplo.

Espero que sirva.